# Problem with the alignment in systeme package

Tags: debugging, syntax, systeme

When I type this:

```
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}

\systeme[xyzt]{x-iy+3t=0,ix-z-(2-i)t=0,(1+i)x+(2-i)y+(3i-5)t=0,-ix+(1+i)y+z-it=0}


\end{document}
```

I'm ending up with this:

[image: After compiling the code]

Which, as you see, isn't very convenient.
I read the documentation and it says that when a variable isn't in the [ordering variable box] it isn't treated as a variable, but it seems that the parenthesis are doing some weird stuff.

How can I fix my input to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Your problem can probably be solved easily by inserting curly braces to group the relevant parts (the spacing is just to make the code more readable):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}

\systeme[xyzt]{
    x - iy + 3t = 0,
    ix - z - {(2-i)t} = 0,
    {(1+i)x} + {(2-i)y} + {(3i-5)t} = 0,
    -ix + {(1+i)y} + z - it = 0
}

\end{document}
```

[image]